# Find the list values not in pandas dataframe data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list and pandas dataframe data that looks like this:

```
user_id = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 32, 40, 45, 50]

user_id  value 
10        45 
20        49 
25        19'
30        58
32        48
```

I've try to find user_id list not in list. 
My desired result is

```
result = [15, 40, 45, 50]
```

What is the easiest way to get desired result? 
(Currently I've got the result by for~loop)

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you getting, and how does it differ from what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a set operation:

```
list(set(user_id)-set(df.user_id))
Out[84]: [40, 50, 45, 15]
```

Comment: Good one, I was trying with intersection but this is simpler:)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with negation (`~`).

`df[~df["user_id"].isin(set(user_id))]`

Conversion to *set* is always preferable as you'll better running time.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the user_id column to a list and then use list comprehension to find the ones that are in your original list not in the other list.

```
user_id = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 32, 40, 45, 50]
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [10, 20, 25, 30, 32], 'value': [45, 49, 19, 58, 48]}
df_user_id = df['user_id'].tolist()
result = [x for x in user_id if x not in df_user_id]

[15, 40, 45, 50]
```